# Cron jobs not running on Kubernetes + Alpine linux

Tags: linux, docker, cron, kubernetes, alpine-linux

I am trying to run a cron job on Alpine Linux docker image which is then pushed in Kubernetes container. The Cron job is that I want the container to restart itself after every 15 mins. So my command is `pkill processname`.

Little bit about Alpine Cron jobs: For Alpine Linux cron is followed periodically that is it has already created folders /15min. /hourly. /daily. /weekly. /monthly. So I have to just copy my script in one of the folders to run it.

I created the script and as requested on Alpine FAQ's pages I didn't give any name extension to the file and copied it with execute permissions in the folder. When I try and run command `run-parts --test /etc/periodic/15min` it shows me that it has one script that needs to be executed. Although that script never executes. When I try and run that docker image on my local machine, not exactly with that script but a different one where I am just creating a file in the folder, it works well.

I have also tried and run `crond -f -l 8` on Kube cluster and ti still does not work.

I would really appreciate help on this part what I am missing or where is it going wrong.

Comment: I know this may be a bit silly, but are you totally sure it is actually not executing the process? Maybe it is running and not producing the desired behaviour because of permissions? This is a common problem. I'm not familiar with Alpine Linux logging, but you can schedule a script that creates a new file (touch <path>) in a 777 folder. If the file doesnt appear, the script is not executing, if it does, it means that you dont have permission to kill that process or execute pkill at all. Also, check on the main cron configuration if the line for 15 minute cronjobs is commented out.

Comment: I assumed in my comment that you checked that you have the correct syntax on your command that that it actually works if you execute it manually. Also, for maintainability and testing reasons, I usually suggest to create a .sh script that does the job and then schedule it, even if it is just one line. It is allways easier to change and migrate things given that scenario, and you'll get less errors due to lack of attention during repetitive tasks specially if spaces are involved. Have you ever lost a closing " which is the last character while copying something out? It is really anoying

Comment: Some references I found: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015624/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-container-alpine/7759

Check cron log: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Comment: I tried to run the pkill command from the command prompt and it work perfectly fine. As you have said I tried doing the touch command it worked fine on my local docker image but it does not run on the Kube cluster. For Alpine linux they have mentioned that you should not create a .sh file, they have mentioned that you need to create a file without extensions to work. I have checked links that you have mentioned and tried it, but that does not work as well. On that docker image on Kube I cannot do sudo not su for any of the commands.

Comment: oh, I added a custom answer but it doesnt add much info. Please, try to find the log files and see if CRON is giving any errors. Also, create a file (without extension if you must) and redirect the output of the command to a file so see if something is going wrong. Redirect output to file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file. This should show nothing, as it is actually not running

Comment: Please, check https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/ and https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs?hl=es-419 aswell

Comment: check my answer again. Modified it with specific restarting info about kubernetes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wellcome to SuperUser.

First of all, maybe you're facing it the wrong way. If the goal is to restart the complete container every 15 minutes, maybe you should check the links bellow.

[Question about restarting pods with multiple possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422300/how-to-schedule-pods-restart)

[Pod lifecycle documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/)

[Kubernetes concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/) - Explanation about how kubernetes works and the names people uses for things there.

Just for completity, and in case you actually want to run a periodic task, **check specific Kubernetes docs**, they state how to create cronjobs and debug them. I'd also suggest to read about Kubernetes limitations in documentation, as there may be something actively preventing to run your cronjobs

[GCP Documentation about cronjobs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs?hl=es-419)

[Kubernetes documentation about Cronjobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

I'm giving you a resume about how to create a cronjob task, but you should carefully read the above if you're not familiar with kubernetes and follow the links inside, they've environments ready to play and learn the basics of kubernetes.

It is more elaborated inside, but it basically gives you an example command and the way to deploy it. I've modified it to be once every 15 minutes and run a pkill. You've to create a yaml file with the following contents (check syntax for more complex cron behaviours):

```
# cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/15 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - pkill yourprocess
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

and then deploy it using

```
kubectl apply -f [FILENAME]
```

Use the following command to check if your cronjob was deployed:

```
kubectl describe cronjob [CRON_JOB]
```

[Post describing the above processes with more screenshots and examples](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-running-background-tasks-with-batch-jobs-56482fbc853)

After this point this is a very generic answer. You can post comments and I'll try to help you out, but I currently have no access to an Alpine Linux installation, so I may not be helpful. [This is the Alpine Linux documentation page addressing your issue](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#My_cron_jobs_don.27t_run.3F)

**Tracing your error: The simple way**

There's a very simple way to narrow down whats going out, although it is not very precise. There are two chances here: There's a problem with CRON itself, or you have a problem with your script (permissions, for instance). The process is simple:

- Create a task that creates an empty file inside a folder where you're ABSOLUTLY SURE everyone can read and write.
- If the new file appears when the task is suposed to run, it means that your cron is executing properly and that you have a problem with your script. Go to "Script problems" section. If not, you've a problem with cron. Go to Cron problems section

**Tracing your error: Logs**

The best way to solve problems in any system is looking at the logs. Software like cron normally stores logs on syslog (normally located at /var/log/syslog), unless configured otherwise. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) speaks about cron logging folders.

If you find out where your cron instance is logging and there's nothing there, it means that your cron service is not running at all. There's a Alpine Linux specific solution for this problem in Cron problems. If you can see errors, you should look at them and try to narrow down your problem. If not, you should make sure that your script is actually not running.

**Cron problems**

Ok, now you know cron is not working properly. There are various possible scenarios:

- Cron is not running at all

Maybe the cron service is not started. Check if the service is running. If it is not, try to start it manually. Check if it has started properly and then add it to startup process. The way to do so varies depending on the OS. In Alpine Linux, this should do the trick:

```
rc-service crond start && rc-update add crond
```

- The cron folder you're using is not being used by cron

You should check the main cron config file in order to verify that the folder you're putting scripts on is actually added.

- Typos

Maybe the config line has some error with spaces on arguments or things like that, although in this case this seem not to be the scenario, as you used test commands on your folder.

**Script problems**

If your script runs but it is not producing the desired output, it is a good idea to perform the following steps:

- Separate your script into a file. Give it run permissions and ensure that the first line properly states the shell to use, in Alpine's case, this line should be #!/bin/sh
- [Redirect the standard and error output to a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) to analize what's going on.

**General suggestions**

- As stated in Script problems section, it is a good practise to separate your oneliners into script files and point their output to files, in order to be able to debug problems of all kinds.
- Take a close look at directory and file permissions (those directly accesed by your script and those that cron should read / user in order to execute your scripts), it is a common cause of failure, specially in containers.

**EDIT: Maybe I understood your situation in the wrong way and you're in an scenario like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431902/running-a-cronjob-in-a-pod-in-kubernetes)**

Comment: Thank you @DGoiko, the issue was with the permissions. All the cron folders are in root access and the user is in 1000 access. I'm now trying to figure out a way to give crond root access

Comment: keep in mind that the behaviour may be intentional. Check my edits about restarting pods and kubernetes cronjobs

Comment: What is happening is I am defining the a Dockerfile to putting the script undet /etc/periodic/15min which is under root user, now to start the cron jobs I need to run command crond -f -l 8. When I try and run this command it runs on 1000 user and not root user, I guess that's why it cannot access the root script as it does not allow it to run, so now I need to find a way to run the command crond -f -l 8 under root user. In my kube config as you said for security reasons, no root user is allowed. only 1000 user is allowed.

Comment: I see. In that case, I'd try to go either with the native kubernetes CronJob approach or the links that explain lifecycle / restarting of pods (all cases linked above). IF that doesn't work or fullfill your needs, THEN you should investigate about the  crond -f -l 8 situation.

Comment: I cannot restart the pod, like thats not possible. Let me check the kubernetes CronJob approach, if I can kill a process in one of the containers in Kube. I'm not sure if Kube cron job can do it, because I want it to go in 1 of the 2 containers and kill a specific process.